# Torch: Index operator with string returning the original array no matter what the input string

Tags: torch

Perhaps not of great practical concern but still tickles my curiosity.

When looking at the index operator syntax for torch, I was led to try v[{''}], which to my surprise returned the original table. And so did any arbitrary input string, such as v[{'abc'}] and v[{'what ever str you can think of'}].

Is this an intended behavior? If so, for what purpose?